# How to Create Data Model to be extended in different components/routes

Tags: angular, angular4-httpclient

I have a to form a request object for different POST services at different routes.

service 1 takes request Obj as {
   fname: '',
lname: '',
age: 23,
....
...etc
}

service 2 takes request as {
   fname: '',
lname: '',
age: 23,
address: []
....
...etc
}
service 3 takes request as {
   fname: '',
lname: '',
age: 23,
address: [],
hobbiles:[],
....
...etc
}

The request object should be extended with a few attributes/properties.

Please suggest how I can create a Model for this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You have several options:

1) You could build the model to define the full set of possible properties and add the "?" to those that are optional. (Not required in every service.)

2) You can build a base model and extend it ... but that may not be worth the time unless there is enough difference in logic when handling those services.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  If we create an interface for base model, how can we carry the previous request object to next route/component?

Comment: Not sure I understand? You can build a service that holds the instance of the model and is passed to the different components.